# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access

Every now and then I get one of the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors that seem to plague new Objective-C programmers.

In my program I'm trying to get a get the time in seconds, convert that to a string and then  convert that to a `NSData` object for writing to a file. Here is the code I'm using, but it crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` every time I run it.  What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void) startTheClock{

    NSTimeInterval cloqInTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSString * dateStr = [self stringFromTimeInterval:cloqInTime];

    NSData * data = [[dateStr stringByAppendingString:@", "] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog([@"Data:" stringByAppendingString:[data description]]);


// [data retain]; // <-- Uncommenting this and the [data release] line doesn't prevent the error
   [self writeData:data]; // <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens here!
// [data release];
}
```

When I run this method I get the following output:

```
timeString: |2011-11-04 16:17:12|
Data:<32303131 2d31312d 30342031 363a3137 3a31322c 20>
```

As requested here is my `stringFromTimeInterval` method:

```
-(NSString *) stringFromTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)t{
    NSDate * date  = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:t];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    NSString *timeString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"timeString: %@", timeString);    
    return timeString;
}
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
#0  0x00007fff84407e90 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x00000001054543f0 in 0x00000001054543f0 ()
#2  0x00000001000012ee in -[WorqAppDelegate startTheClock] at /Users/slayton/Documents/Xcode/Worq/Worq/WorqAppDelegate.m:61
#3  0x0000000100001164 in -[WorqAppDelegate cloqInAction:] at /Users/slayton/Documents/Xcode/Worq/Worq/WorqAppDelegate.m:37
#4  0x00007fff8cbb9a1d in -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] ()
#5  0x00007fff86f69710 in -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] ()
#6  0x00007fff86f69642 in -[NSControl sendAction:to:] ()
#7  0x00007fff86f6956d in -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] ()
#8  0x00007fff86f68a30 in -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] ()
#9  0x00007fff86fe88e0 in -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] ()
#10 0x00007fff86f6763a in -[NSControl mouseDown:] ()
#11 0x00007fff86f320e0 in -[NSWindow sendEvent:] ()
#12 0x00007fff86eca68f in -[NSApplication sendEvent:] ()
#13 0x00007fff86e60682 in -[NSApplication run] ()
#14 0x00007fff870df80c in NSApplicationMain ()
#15 0x0000000100001092 in main ()
```

Here is the `writeData` method, `recordFile` is an instance of `NSFileHandle`:

```
-(BOOL) writeData:(NSData *)data{
    if (recordFile != NULL)
        [recordFile writeData:data];
    else
        NSLog(@"Record file is null! No data written");
}
```

Comment: Show us your `stringFromTimeInterval:` method.

Comment: Show us the stack trace and your `writeData:` method.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line that calls `writeData:`.  Before it does the call, do `po self` and `p *self` in the debugger.  Does everything look ok?

Comment: @robmayoff, nothing looks out of order however I'm not super familiar with gdb

Comment: Keep an eye on your **recordFile** object. I'm wondering if this object has been over-released (and thus deallocated) but is not nil. This would cause the **[recordFile writeData:data]** method to throw an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. What is the lifespan of recordFile?

Comment: @craig, thanks so much! I added [recordFile retain] after its created and that fixed the problem! If you write up this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @slayton Posted as an answer. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep an eye on your `recordFile` object. I'm wondering if this object has been over-released (and thus deallocated) but is not `nil`. This would cause the `[recordFile writeData:data]` method to throw an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. What is the lifespan of `recordFile`?

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb, but I'd say that `data` is probably `nil`. Have you checked the value of `data`?

Answer (score 0):

the debugger and in particular the stack trace is your friend, but yeah, most likely data is nil.

in the debugger window at the prompt, type:  po data

or better, just look at the local variables in the left pane and see what data's value is.